# How to convert the php code to jquery

Tags: php, jquery

What does this line mean

```
$country = isset($_GET['country']) && !empty($_GET['country']) ? urlencode($_GET['country']) : 'us';
```

I also want the jquery version of it.

Comment: you need a php-to-jquery converter ;)

Comment: is there any php-to-jquery converter

Comment: No, there is not. PHP is server-side, JQuery is Client-side.

Comment: I believe I saw something called pQuery before that adds jQuery style syntax and DOM manipulation/selection to PHP, but yeah, one does not simply convert server side to client side

Answer (score 3):

making it as simple as i can,

this mean ,

> if  $_GET['country'] is set and it is not empty
>         $country = urlencode($_GET['country']);
>      else
>         $country =us

these is called if else ternary operator ..here is the [link](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) to read more about it

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var country = 'us';
    var getQueryPairs = location.search.split('&');
    var getQueryVar;
    for (var i = 0; i < getQueryPairs.length; i++) {
      getQueryVar = getPairs[i].split('=');
      if (getQueryVar[0] == 'country' && getQueryVar[1]) country = getQueryVar[1];
    }
    alert(country);
</script>
```

Comment: Did you... _really_ just create a parser for that particular statement with regards to the navigation bar? Lmao.

Comment: happy to make smart asses ltao. that's what I'm here for.

Comment: It wasn't meant as an insult - I just never expected someone to post a literal answer to a question like this.  Hell, I give +1 because it does answer the question, it just took me by surprise.

Comment: haha. I did get offended at first, but the clarification helped. sorry, please disregard my comment above & tnx for the +1!

Comment: No problem at all.  When I first saw the answer I wasn't sure if you were being a smartass by posting such a literal answer to the question.. but that's because I was stuck on someone trying to convert server-side to client-side and that just baffled me when doing it with PHP available just seems... I don't know. ^^

Answer (score 0):

That is just testing to see if the submitted form element called country was set and is not empty, if so then set the country, otherwise set a default of "us"

this is a ternary IF statement where if it's true the code to the left of the colon is assigned to $country, and if it is false it assigns the code on the right to the $country variable.

$this = (1 == 1) ? "it was one" : "it wasn't one";

Comment: a) There is no `if` in a ternary operator.  b) you have your ternary operators in the incorrect order. ^^

Comment: You're welcome. ^^  Though, I must say, I do like your explanation in the first sentence there. =]

Answer (score 0):

This means if make sure you have $_GET['country'] superglobal variable and it is not empty. If it is not then it will do urlencoding of that variable or else will set $country = us.

Answer (score 0):

Means:
If `country` has been passed to the page via GET and `country` has something in it, it should set `$country` to the appropriate country code. It will default to 'us'.

You would not be able to do this via jQuery alone, as the `$_GET` data would not be available to you on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the question you want answered, but it does answer the question in your title (to a degree). In case anyone ends up here looking for that, there is a php library called phpQuery which attempts to emulate jQuery style syntax (especially method chaining) and selector-based DOM manipulation. As pointed out in the comments, PHP is a server side language, so you are not exactly going to have the level of control over the browser demonstrated in actual jQuery; but if you are doing mainly jQuery development client side, I can see how using similar syntax for your server side code might be more useful/comfortable/easy.

As an aside, when this post first reminded me of this library I thought it was called pQuery - google informs me that this is a similar project to bring make perl more jQuery-y.